# More than one extremal for an isoperimetric problem?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am trying to find the extremal (if it exists) of the isoperimetric problem with the functional:
$I[x] = \int_0^1(\dot{x}^2+2x)dt$
subject to the conditions:

$\int_0^1 2x dt = 3$, $x(0) = -1$, $x(1) = 4$

I use the Mayer equations to derive a value of an extremal in terms of Lagrange multipliers. When I solve for these multipliers, **I get two possible values and therefore two extremums. Is this possible? Is it possible to have two extremums for this problem? I've only ever been used to solving for one.**

Comment: Trivial algebraic mistake, we meet again

Comment: You don't need the multiplier,  just to minimize $$\int_0^1\dot{x}^2dt$$